# Using git, how do you move some uncommitted changes from one branch to another branch in a different folder?

Tags: git

I have two different branches of the same software that I work on every day.  However, every time I checkout the other branch, my build process can take up to an hour.  To solve this, I have just checked out the project once for each branch in two separate folders.

I did some work in one branch, and realized before committing it that I was in the wrong folder, and thus the wrong branch.  How can I move the work I did on this branch, to the other branch, preferably without creating a commit (if that is even possible)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the directory with the changes, do:

```
$ git diff > patch
```

cd to the other directory, and do:

```
git apply /path/to/patch
```

Comment: This should work, though I might shrink it a bit more. `cd project2 && (cd ../project1 && git diff) | git apply`. No need to write a patchfile to disk.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I used `git diff > patch`, `git reset --hard`, then moved to the correct branch and `git apply patch`.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can also not build the other branch..

1. Make the change, don't commit
2. Switch to the other branch
3. Commit (don't build)
4. Come back

Naturally, this only works if you can allow yourself to commit without building (reasonable in some scenarios).