# Move uncommited changes to a different computer without commiting

Tags: git

I have 2 development machines.

I have made uncommitted changes to the repo in machine A. These uncommitted changes includes both edits & newly created files.

I wish to move these uncommitted changes to machine B. NOTE: I do NOT want to commit these changes to the repo and pull them from machine B, becuase I don't want people to see unfinished code in BitBucket commit logs.

Note that both machine A and B has the latest version of the current repository.

According to this:
[Using git, how do you move some uncommitted changes from one branch to another branch in a different folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855318/using-git-how-do-you-move-some-uncommitted-changes-from-one-branch-to-another-b)

I should do this in machine A

```
$ git diff > patch
```

Send the patch file to mahcine B and do this:

```
$ git apply /path/to/patch
```

This usually works. But in this case the git apply fails.

When I perform `$ git apply --check` I get errors similar to the following:

```
error: database/migrations/example.php: No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: *“I do NOT want to commit these changes to the repo”* – Why not?

Comment: Why are you so opposed to commiting them? Remember you can commit, then once you pull on the other machine you can `reset --soft` to "uncommit" them.

Comment: Or use a branch and then delete the branch when you're done.

Comment: *"This usually works"* -- this always works if the current branch on machine `B` is the same as the current branch on machine `A` when you created the commit. Otherwise it is similar to a rebase and it might encounter conflicts.

Comment: @pokeBecuase these changes are very incomplete and not ready for a commit.

Comment: As the comments above say, your life will be maximally easy if you do this through Git's commit system.  A commit is not permanent, can be reworked, etc.

Comment: @CoryKramer @Holloway@Tim Biegeleisen I would be open to any of these ideas as answers. Provided the is no permanent commit in BitBucket, where people can see unfinished code.

Comment: Feature or work-in-progress branches are exactly made for this. Just push to a different branch. If you are really worried that people might see uncomplete code (why though?), then you can quickly delete the commit directly after pulling, or simply use a *different remote* for the transfer. Git is a distributed version control system, so you could even just push directly to the target repository.

Comment: @axiac I am on the same branch and on the same commit. So I'm unsure why it's struggling when it comes to new files.

Comment: @CoryKramer @Holloway@Tim Biegeleisen Feel free to post comments as extended answers, as you made some good points.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to push all branches to BitBucket (or whatever central repository you use). Set computer `A` as remote in the repo hosted on computer `B`, use `git fetch A` to get the branches from `A` then do whatever you want with the fetched commits.

Run once on computer `B`:

```
git remote add A <url-of-the-repo-on-A>
```

Replace `<url-of-the-repo-on-A>` with an URL you can use on `B` to access the repo located on the `A` computer.
For example, assuming on `A` the repo is located in `/home/user1/projects/repo` and you can access `A` from `B` using `ssh` as `user1` you can use `ssh://B/home/user1/projects/repo`. (You need to configure `A` and `B` to use public keys for authentication to not be bugged by Git about your password on `A` every time it needs to access the remote repository).

If you have a different way of communication between `A` and `B` (f.e. a directory shared by `A` that is mounted on `B`) you can use it as well (assuming the repo on `B` is visible this way).

After the initial set up step, every time you want to transfer the changes from `A` to `B` you can create a new commit on `A` (on whatever branch you want, maybe you want to create a branch special for this transfer). Then you login on `B` and run (in the repo):

```
git fetch A
```

(`A` is the name of the repository set by the `git remote` command above).
This brings into the local repo all the commits that are new in `A` and are not present in the local repo. You can, as well, fetch a single branch by putting it into the command line:

```
git fetch A branch1
```

Now, that the changes are in `B` you can check the branch out and continue working on it:

```
git checkout branch1
```

Or move them on top of another branch (using `rebase`) or merge them or do whatever you want.

Read more about [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) and [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).